# A closed form for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \prod_{k=1}^{i+2} (3k+2)$

Tags: summation, closed-form, products

I need to calculate the following expression. Is there any explanation to convert this expression into normal expression without those letters for sum and the product? Just normal expression.

> $$ Z = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{i+2} (3k+2). $$

Comment: This is a "normal" expression.

Comment: This is a beautiful formula. You would be surprised but the result Z[n] has a closed form (involving a few functions which would look terrible) !

Comment: The last term in this sum has $n+1$ factors each greater than or equal to $2$, so $Z(n)>2^n$ and therefore cannot be expressed as a rational function in $n$ (it cannot be written using only $+$, $-$, $\cdot$ and $/$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this is a "normal expression". This notation comes up a lot in any type of math and so you should get used to it. The summation notation sums the enclosed expression from the lower bound to the upper bound. The product notation does the same but for products. So, for example, $$ \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{i+2} (3k+2) $$ multiplies $3k+2$ for $k=1$, $k=2$, etc., but to $i+2$. This yields an expression in terms of the upper bound $i$, which then gets summed by the $ \displaystyle\sum $.

Comment: Wouldn't it multiply 3k+2 for k=1, k=3, k=4, k=5 etc?

Comment: What is your question? Could you rephrase please?

Comment: Well, you said it would multiply 3k+2 for k=1,k=2 etc, I'm asking you why it's k=1, k=2, etc.. not k=1, and then k=3, since it's increasing for i+2 and i=1 for first value?

Comment: No. $i+2$ is the upper bound. The **increment** is just $1$, unless otherwise stated. If you wanted it to consider only the odds, you would either adjust that in the argument or you would write $$ \displaystyle\prod_{k \in \{ 1, 3, 5, \cdots i + 2 \}} $$ or something of that sort, suggesting that there was an increment of $2$. But there isn't here.

Comment: Sorry. What does the upper bound mean and what is its usage?

Comment: Upper bound means the highest value that it goes. For example, $$ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{5} i $$ is $ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 $ and $$ \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{3} $$ is $ 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 $.

Comment: I understand now. And then when the product is calculated it sums it up with the sum of the same expression (3k+2)?

Comment: No. The sum is done on the expression that is found from the product. For example, $$ \begin {align*} \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{3} \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{j} i &= \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{3} \left( 1 \cdot 2 \cdots j \right) \\&= \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{3} j! \\&= 1! + 2! + 3!. \end {align*} $$ Does that make more sense? Thanks for the accept, by the way! No up vote? :P

Comment: Well. In this case, let's say n=3. I'll have k=1, k=2, k=3. Therefore, I'll get (3*1+2) * (3*2+2) * (3*3+2) = 5 * 8 * 11 = 440. And from 440, then I'll add the sum? I can't upvote, I don't meet the requiremenets.

Comment: You don't plug in an $n=3$. That's an index. Don't worry about the up vote!

Comment: Well, I have to write a program in a programming language for inputted 'n' in the sum to calculate it. Therefore, n has to be a number..

Comment: By the way, you should take a look at [this link](http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/SummationNotation) and [this link](http://mathmaine.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/sigma-and-pi-notation/). They talk in depth about this type of notation and about nests.

Comment: Looks interesting! Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of service. :)